# WinForms calls Webservice which timeouts but does not call Complete

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services, asynchronous

I have a WinForms app that calls a web service and uses the Async...Completed pattern.

However, sometimes the Completed call is never called (prob due to timeout).

I thought timeout would call Completed with an error - but it is NEVER called.

Any well-known gotchas (that I don't know about) as to why this would be?

Thanks
Duncan

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at episode 188 on dnrtv.

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=188

Stephen Toub walks us through what asynch code should look like in .NET 4, both consumer and production side, as well as a dive inot the upcoming asynch of .NET 5. Well worth the watch even if you are sticking to .NET 4.